# Kendo ui treeview expand path with loadondemand true

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-treeview

Kendo ui treeview expanding the path when load on demand is true is working fine for single path. If I have array of paths treeview is not expanding and checking the checkboxes its happening with multiple button clicks.

The below code fetches the paths I need to expand

```
public JsonResult GetFilteredDataByVal(string[] FilterString)
{
List<string> Ids = new List<string>();
Ids.Add("1000,1001,24935,27179,27195,27196");
Ids.Add("1000,1001,24916");
return Json(Ids, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and I am lopping in javascript to expand

```
for (var i = 0;i<value.length;i++)
    {
        var selectId = value[i].split(',').pop();
        treeview.expandPath(value[i].split(','), function () {

            var dataitem = treeview.dataSource.get(selectId);

            if (dataitem) {
                var node = treeview.findByUid(dataitem.uid);
                //
                if (node) {
                    treeview.dataItem(node).set("checked", true);
                    treeview.select(node);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

can you guys help me to expand the both paths and check the last node from the paths at once.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome SO! Please post a working jsfiddle that reproduce your problem.

Comment: I don't have it in jsfiddle

Comment: You have to take the time to build a jsfiddle if you want someone to help you